# Leaflet heatmap: how do I plots points with a point-specific radius that scales with zoom?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leaflet and leaflet-heatmap to do the following.  I have a few points showing locations of interest, and each one is associated with a certain radius that corresponds to how walkable each location is (for example 3 miles, 5 miles, etc.).  I'd like to:

1). Surround each point with some "blob" corresponding to this point's radius, ideally so it would become fainter as one moves away from the point's center

2). Scale the radius appropriately as I zoom in and out of the map.

Here's my javascript:

```
 //just some sample single location
text = "lat;long;walk\n39.1101;-84.5758;3";

var lines = text.split("\n");
var heatData = [];
for (var i=1; i<lines.length; i++) {
    var parts = lines[i].split(",");
    heatData.push( [ parts[0], parts[1], 1. ]  )
}

var heat = L.heatLayer(heatData, {radius: 20, blur: 10, scaleRadius: true, max: 0.1, max_zoom: 20 }).addTo(map);
```

For question 1: would 'radius' be the right quantity to feed the walkability radius (heatData[ 2 ]) to?  If so, how do I do that?

For question 2: below are images of a point zoomed in and zoomed out, you see that the radius of a blob surrounding the point does not scale properly

Zoomed in:

[image: Point zoomed in - area of walkability seems small]

Zoomed out - the radius stays constant but I want it to be smaller, to reflect the actual area of walkability relative to the new scale:

[image: point zoomed out - area of walkability seems huge]

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

I would make raster heatmap layers for each of the radius values (3 miles, 5 miles, etc.) and add them as layers to your map. Then at all zoom levels they will be the right distance from the point and you won't have to use a complicated function to change the clustering of the heatmap.